# Why my loop does not show a good result in HTML?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, sqlite, pyqt5

I have a problem with making loops to show me my data from database. Everything works fine to the section where it should display the loop in HTML. When I simply print the data, they are displayed well but when it needs to be displayed in html they are displayed only once and show me only the last entry

code:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM telImenik ")



self.htmlKod = ""
self.num_rows = 0
for i in range(0, 126):
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    print(row[0])
    self.htmlKod = """<tr><td style='padding:5px;'> {L} </td>
                            <td style='padding:5px;'>{P}</td>
                            <td style='padding:5px;'>{I}</td>
                            <td style='padding:5px;'>{T}</td>
                            <td style='padding:5px;'>{Lok}</td></tr>



                         """.format(L=row[0], P=row[1], I=row[2], T=row[3], Lok=row[4])

    self.num_rows = self.num_rows + 1

self.document = QTextDocument()

self.html = """
       <!DOCTYPE html><html lang='en'>
       <title>BS Admin</title>
       <head>
       <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
       </head>
       <body style='margin:0;'>  
       <table width='100%'  border=0 style='color:black;font-weight:bold;'>
       <tr>
       <td width='50%'>Naziv<br>VAdresa</td>
       <td width='50%'><img src='ikonice/logo.png' align='right' ></td>
       </tr>
       </table>  <br>
       <center><h1>POdaci</h1></center><br>

       <table width='100%'  border=1 style='color:black;font-weight:bold;border-color:silver;' cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
       """ + self.htmlKod + """
       </table>
       </body></html>
       """.format('', '')

cursor.close()
konekcija.close()
```

Comment: Why the `.format('', '')` at the end of `self.html = """..."""`? You probaly want to replace the `""" + self.htmlKod + """` with a `{}` placeholder and then use `.format(self.htmlKod)` to put the tablerows in that slot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for` loop replaces the string each iteration:

```
self.htmlKod = ""
for i in range(0, 126):
    # ...
    self.htmlKod = """...""".format(...)
```

`self.htmlKod =` does not combine the strings, so in the end only the last assignment wins.

But rather than use `+=` to concatenate the strings, build a *list*, then use `str.join()` at the end. That's more efficient as it avoids repeated copies of a growing string each time you add more text:

```
rows = []
for i in range(0, 126):
    # ...
    row.append("""...""".format(...))

self.htmlKod = "".join(rows)
```